# Gimp can't import .ufraw

Tags: 16.04, gimp

Gimp reports error message

```
Opening '/tmp/DSC_<filenumber>.NEF_<UFraw reference>.ufraw' failed:    
Could not open '<filename>' for reading: Unknown reason
```

after processing Nikon `.nef` file.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, Gimp 2.8.16 (and 2.8.18) UFRaw 0.20. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you installed the GIMP plug-in for UFRaw?  `sudo apt install gimp-ufraw `

Comment: I apologise for the delay coming back to you. I only just found your response. It works fine thank you.  I knew it was something simple that I was missing.

Comment: I'm going to write that as an answer so that it can help others if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

There is a GIMP plug-in that supports UFRaw.

To install it, run the following from a terminal window:

```
sudo apt install gimp-ufraw
```

Hope this helps!